# Variable changed randomly in backtrace

Tags: c

We are observing a strange issue.
The C application is crashing with a segmentation fault. The trigger is unknown yet. On analysis of the core dump, a strange behavior is observed in the backtrace.

Note: this is a single threaded application running on a freeBSD OS. This is production coredump and the compiler optimizations were enabled.

Below is the snippet of the backtrace:

```
#6  0x08282b61 in efree (block=0xf2bdcaff, type=EMALLOC_DB) 
415         free(block);
(gdb) f 7
#7  0x0824c0f3 in db_entry_free (db_entry=0xd662680, obj_type=<optimized out>) 
765                 efree(db_entry->db_msg, EMALLOC_DB);
(gdb) p db_entry->db_msg
$6 = (rts_msg_union *) 0xe2c0180
```

It can be seen in frame 7, `efree()` is called with the pointer `0xe2c0180` as the first parameter.
But in frame 6, we can see that the first parameter has a different value `0xf2bdcaff`.

It is confirmed that the function `efree()` doesn't modify the variable block until line number 415.

Not sure what could be going wrong here.

Can somebody please provide any pointers on how to debug this?

Regards,
MCP

Comment: Backtraces from optimized code are tricky.  The compiler may have substantially rearranged the code so that it executes in a very different order from what's written in the source.  It also might reuse memory in clever ways.  Then, there is the possibility that the value of `db_entry->db_msg` was overwritten after a copy was passed to `efree`.  The best way I know to investigate is to read the assembly and sort out what values are actually in what registers / memory locations at the time of the crash.

Comment: Likewise, the possibility that the local parameter `block` was written to within `efree`, which of course would not affect the value of `db_entry->db_msg`.

Comment: Make sure it's not an hardware failure -> memory, CPU, mainboard error | What kind of CPU do you use?